# Cannot connect the local host in android emulator

Tags: java, postgresql, android-studio, django-rest-framework, android-emulator

I have seen this question has been asked before, but the resolutions didn't work for me so far. Hopefully someone can shed some light on what I am doing wrong:

I have djangorestframework+postgresql as my back-end on my laptop. android project is also on the same laptop.

In browser I can access to a json string by for example the following URL on my laptop when server is running:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/

now on my android emulator I am using the following (as suggested in many resolutions) to fetch the json string:

http://10.0.2.2:8000/posts/

but it responds as Bad Request.

I wanted to make sure the setup is right in Android project so I tested and saw that it can read json api from internet URLs with no issue.

I also am using okhttp3 to fetch json from url.

Would someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,

here is my Java code:

```
url2 = "http://10.0.2.2:8000/posts/";

client = new OkHttpClient();
request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url2)
        .build();


client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            final String jsonResponse = response.body().string();
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    m_textView.setText(jsonResponse);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.d("AMIRSERVER", jsonResponse);
        }
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue but my backend is on IIS in C# on Win10. I just modified the project 'hosts' file to accept 192.168.0.1 and 10.0.2.2 IPs. Before it was just accepting calls to 'localhost' as it as the only entry in the 'hosts' file.

Your server may have something like that...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Erich,
I put

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["10.0.2.2"]
```

in my Django settings and it worked!!!